# How to globally disable autoescape of Django templates?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using Django templates in a non HTML environment, so naturally I'd like to turn off HTML auto escaping.
How do I turn it off on a global level?

I know about the plethora of options to suppress auto escape locally:

- [django.utils.safestring.mark_safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)
- [safe filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)
- [autoescape tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape)
- [autoescape constructor argument of Context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/template/context/)

These options suppress a globally enabled auto escape, where in my use case I'd like to have the reverse.

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates) there should be an 'autoescape' option for the DjangoTemplates backend.
I even found the [feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25469) and [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/19a5f6da329d58653bcda85f84efd5d5eaf68f84) that added it.

Yet it does not seem to work for me.

Minimal example:

```py
from django.template import Context
from django.template import Template
import django
from django.conf import settings

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "OPTIONS":
            {
            "autoescape": False
            }
    }
]
settings.configure(TEMPLATES=TEMPLATES)
django.setup()

template = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
context = Context({"my_name": "<FooBar>"})
print(template.render(context))
```

Expected output:
`My name is <FooBar>.`

Actual output:
`My name is &lt;FooBar&gt;.`

I am probably missing something stupid.
Could someone enlighten me?

My virtual environment:

```
python==3.6.5  
Django==2.1.7  
pip==9.0.3  
pytz==2018.9  
setuptools==39.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that a template created directly from the Template class does not take into account any of the settings. For that, you need to get the template via an Engine. This would work:

```
from django.template import engines
template = engines['django'].from_string("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
context = {"my_name": "<FooBar>"}
print(template.render(context))
```

As you can see, the added benefits include a `from_string` method and the ability to pass a dict directly rather than creating a Context instance.

Comment: How can you mark the context variable as a SafeString so the example prints `<FooBar>` and not `&lt;FooBar&gt;`? `mark_safe()` would not work with a dict.